# removing a string using Regex and lookahead

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have one string which is like this:

```
</p>\r\n<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/id/image.png" >
```

Now I want to remove "https://domain.com" from src if it is there without token, for example

```
</p>\r\n<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/id/image.png" >
```

here I would like to remove https://domain.com

Another example

```
</p>\r\n<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/token/123/id/image.png" >
```

In this case I don't want to replace https://domain.com since it contains **token**
So I have written the following code

```
re.sub('(?!.*/token/).*(img src="https://domain\.com)','img src="',a)
```

I successfully removes the domain but it also removes **<** of the img

The output I am getting is

```
</p>\r\nimg src="/article/id/image.png" >
```

while I am expecting

```
</p>\r\n<img src="/article/id/image.png" >
```

I know I can get the desired output by adding < before img in substitution , or by any other method such as string.replace or any other but I am trying to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Regardless of an actual solution to your problem, the `.*` eats up everything up to the end of the line and gives characters back as required. In order to have the `<` as well, you need to write: `re.sub('(?!.*/token/).*(<img src="https://domain\.com)','<img src="',a)`

Comment: re.findall catches the correct string i.e **img src="https://domain.com** , so shouldn't it just replace this part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** To remove `https://domain.com`, please try the following regex:

```
import re
pattern = '(<img\s+src=")(https?://[^/]+)(?!.*?token[^\s]+"\s+>)'
url1 = '</p>\r\n<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/id/image.png" >'
url2 = '</p>\r\n<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/token/123/id/image.png" >'
print 'result of url1: \n', re.sub(pattern, r'\1',url1), '\n'
print 'result of url2: \n', re.sub(pattern, r'\1',url2)
```

Output:

```
result of url1: 
</p>
<p><img src="/article/id/image.png" > 

result of url2: 
</p>
<p><img src="https://domain.com/article/token/123/id/image.png" >
```

Comment: This is one possible solution, but it does not answers my question.

Comment: I know this works, but my question is why the regex I wrote strips < inspite of catching the correct string.

Comment: `.*` at the end of `(?!.*/token/).*` matches any characters except new line. Because it is greedy, it picks up `/`, since the next group starts from `img src=`. To fix this issue, go with `re.sub('(?!.*/token/).*(<img src="https://domain\.com)','img src="',a)`.